# How can I set the title dynamically per page with Manuel Schoebel's SEO package?

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, seo, iron-router

With Meteor 1.0.3.1 and Iron Router, I need to set the title dynamically for some pages, while defaulting to a certain title for other pages, using [Manuel Schoebel's SEO package](https://atmospherejs.com/manuelschoebel/ms-seo). How can I accomplish setting a dynamic page title for a certain route?

I've set SEO up generally like this:

```
Meteor.startup(->
  [...]
  SEO.config({
    title: 'MusitechHub'
    meta: {
      'description': 'The hub for finding and publishing music technology projects'
    }
  })

  undefined
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the package [README](https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo/#dynamic-seo-data), you can use an `iron:router` `onAfterAction` hook to dynamically set the title to whatever computed value you want :

```
Router.route("/post/:slug", {
  onAfterAction: function() {
    var post = Posts.findOne({
      slug: this.params.slug
    });
    SEO.set({
      title: post.title
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I was trying to use `SEO.config` instead of `SEO.set`. Wasn't aware of the latter, do you know where it is documented?

Comment: Unfortunately, `ms-seo` is one of those packages small enough not to receive dedicated documentation, so you'll have to read the code yourself to learn the exposed API : https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo/blob/master/seo.coffee#L24